# Loading multiple Javascript files onsubmit

Tags: javascript, file, function, call

I have defined 3 javascript files with several functions, and I have event handler onsubmit in each of them (essentially same structure) the problem is, when I insert those 3 files at the bottom of the body section as filepath, only 2 of them are loaded while the third is not, and I cannot understand why...
This is the code:

```
function init() {
    'use strict';

    // Listen to see whether the form has been submitted:
    //get a handle to my form
    var demogrForm = document.getElementById("Demographics");   
    demogrForm.onsubmit = validateInputs;

    console.log("submit");
} // End of init() function.

window.onload = init;
console.log("init");
```

essentially, the function called for each "onsubmit" is different in the 3 files, but the code to handle the call is the same...do you have any idea ?

Comment: sorry, for some reason it did not go through. This is the code:  function init() {
 'use strict';
    
  // Listen to see whether the form has been submitted:
    //get a handle to my form
    var demogrForm = document.getElementById("Demographics");   
 demogrForm.onsubmit = validateInputs;
 console.log("submit");
    
   } // End of init() function.
  window.onload = init;
  console.log("init");

Comment: Do you have this code in all three javascript files, with only the elementId different?

Comment: Ok, I fixed it, so here it is how I have done: in the very last javascript file (the third one in my case) you have to call the functions defined in the previous files. Something like

// any code here } // end of function_3 (as defined in the third file)

return function_1(); // as defined in first javascript file return function_2(); // as defined in second javascript file...etc...

window.onload=function(){ console.log("init");

document.getElementById("FormName") = function_3; };

this at least works for me :)

Comment: Yes, window.onload=init; overwrites the function previously assigned to window.onload. And dont'wait too much to learn a framework, like jQuery: it really makes life easier.

Answer (score 0):

Try using jQuery $(function(){}); or change your window.onload. It should look like this:

```
window.onload=function(){
    console.log("init");
    // Listen to see whether the form has been submitted:
    //get a handle to my form
    var demogrForm = document.getElementById("Demographics");   
    demogrForm.onsubmit = validateInputs;

    console.log("submit");
};
```

or using jQuery:

```
$(function(){
    console.log("init");
    // Listen to see whether the form has been submitted:
    //get a handle to my form
    var demogrForm = document.getElementById("Demographics");   
    demogrForm.onsubmit = validateInputs;

    console.log("submit");
});
```

Comment: mmhh...avoiding init() function did not make it...and what function should I call at window.onload=function() ? Beside, I am learning javascript so I would avoid frameworks at this stage, if at all possible